# Webrtc IOS Safari, Enable Torch

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, camera, webrtc

I am trying to get a online camera app working. I would like to know if IOS has any possibility of getting the Flash or Torch triggered from the browser. I dont believe that webrtc torch is supported on IOS. Would there be any alternatives to trigger the flash/torch through extensions or any other means that anyone here is aware of.

Thanks